# References to a private field using Guava Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, guava

I would like to clarify something.

With "plain" Java reflection techniques (without using a library) afaik it is not possible to get a reference to a private field (I mean the `java.lang.reflect.Field` object, no the field value).

For example, if I have this class:

```
public class MyClass {
  private String field1;
}
```

If I attempt to execute this:

```
Field field = MyClass.class.getField("field1");
```

I will get a `NoSuchFieldException` exception, as expected.

With the [Guava Reflection library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-reflection/), if I try to execute this:

```
Object o = new MyClass();
Property property = Properties.getPropertyByName(o, "field1");
Field f = property.getField();
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown property: field1 in class MyClass
```

And this was also expected. However, if I add a getter method, like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  private String field1;
  public String getField1() {return field1;}
}
```

Then the Guava-reflection code is working.
I have to confess I am a bit loss about this. I understand that a reflection library could use a getter to return the value of a private instance variable, but the Field object itself just because a getter exists ?. Does someone has an idea how does this happen ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but have you tried `Field field = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("field1");`? This may be the difference...

Comment: yes, the only problem with that is that getDeclaredField will give me only the fields declared by the class, not by any ancestor. I see how to circumvent the problem (iterating through the ancestors), but looks a bit like writing boring boilerplate code ...

Comment: untagging "Guava" since this question has nothing to do with Guava.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reflect on private fields using standard java reflection, which is probably what Guava is doing under the hood:

```
Class<?> c = ... some class ...
Field field = c.getDeclaredField("name");
field.setAccessible(true);
Object value = field.get(object);
```

`getDeclaredField` allows you to obtain private fields.
`setAccessible` is needed to prevent security issues.

Anyway, as a best practice, consider using reflection on public members only, so work with getters/setters if possible.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you, now I see it is possible, but still it is confusing than in Guava the access to the Field object depends on the existence of a getter.

Comment: I haven't used Guava myself, but this is most likely what happens: In Java, a "property" often means a JavaBean-style property, which is based on an accessor/mutator-pair ("getName" and "setName"). By constructing a property named "name", Guava is probably looking just for the accessor/mutators, as per the JavaBean property convention, not to the field.

Comment: I have just realized that the problem with the getDeclaredField is that it will not answer fields declared by ancestor classes.

Comment: True, you'd have to process the superclasses as well, using Class.getSuperClass().

Answer (score 1):

[Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) extends [AccesibleObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html), which has a method [setAccessible()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject%5B%5D,%20boolean%29), allowing you to get access to the value of a private field.

Guava-Reflection (note that this library is distinct from Guava) is making your private fields accessible in methods like Property.getFieldValue()